# Enquire.js matched two media query

Tags: javascript, media-queries, match, enquire.js

Here's my two media queries

```
@media screen and (min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px)

@media screen and (min-width:1400px) and (min-height:900px)
```

And I'm using Enquire.js to match my media queries

```
enquire
.register("screen and (min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px)", {
    match: function() {
        console.log('1240px');
    },
    unmatch: function() {
        console.log('<1240px');
    },
})
.register("screen and (min-width:1400px) and (min-height:900px)", {
    match: function() {
        console.log('1400px');

    },
    unmatch: function() {
        console.log('<1400px');
    });
```

The problem is if I go from `screen and (min-width:1400px) and (min-height:900px)` to `screen and (min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px)`, equire.js will not match `screen and (min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px)` and that creates a problem. I tried to use unmatch to solve this but then it will unmatch both condition if I go from `screen and (min-width:1400px) and (min-height:900px)` to something smaller than `screen and (min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px)`. Anyone has any solution?

Comment: If you want the media queries to be mutually exclusive (i.e. no overlap) then add a max-width condition to them. e.g. `screen and (min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px) and (max-width:1400px) and (max-height: 900px)`

Comment: I tried that and it's not working. Is there other ways to do so? 'cause without enquire.js, media query works fine with just min-width and min-height, it always goes to the correct one. But it's not working the same in enquire.js... if I don't set an unmatch function for `(min-width:1400px) and (min-height:900px)`, it wouldn't trigger `(min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px)`

Comment: I think I didn't phrase it well, so the main problem is enquire.js didn't match `screen and (min-width:1240px) and (min-height:800px)` when resizing down from `(min-width:1400px) and (min-height:900px)` which media query matched.

Comment: could you whip up a fiddle/codepen to demonstrate the problem? It's hard to reason about without a test case. Cheers